# Jquery: Range Slider: How to get the set range values?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get the set range values using $_POST after form submit. The problem is when range set to 10 - 25, value 10 is the only value got.

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
   $value = $_POST['get'];
   echo "<script> alert($value) </script>";
}

<form method="post">
    <input class="range-slider" type="hidden" name="get"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btn_submit">
</form>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-slider').jRange({
        from: -2.0,
        to: 2.0,
        step: 0.5,
        scale: [-2.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0,2.0],
        format: '%s',
        width: 300,
        showLabels: true,
        snap: true
    });

    $('.range-slider').jRange({
        from: 0,
        to: 100,
        step: 1,
        scale: [0,25,50,75,100],
        format: '%s',
        width: 300,
        showLabels: true,
        isRange : true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have isRange: true in the slider. As mentioned [in the docs:](http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/demo/)

isRange : True if this is a range selector. If its a range the value of hidden input will be set comma-seperated, e.g., "25,75"

You should get the two values if isRange is set to true.

Comment: yes, my isRange is set to true what should i do next?

Answer (score 0):

You can use take two input boxes First for starting range and second for ending range and take values.